# MessageBox in a GPO Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

`Hello Stack Community,

I know this question about how to create a message box in powershell has been responded many times.

I have created a script that install a software for some people and update it regularly through GPO system.
The GPO and the script work as expected and I want to improve this now.

I want to display a popup message when the software is beeing updated.

A preview of what the script does in a simplified version.
1/ Checks the presence of the software folders
2/ Compares the local version with the package available on a file server
3/ Does nothing, Updates the software or installs it regarding the conditions.

```
$currentversion=1.0
$lastversion=1.1
$folder="C:\InstallFolder\"
if(test-path $folder){
    if($currentversion -eq $lasterversion){
 Do not update
    }else{
 Update and **display message box  **
    }
}else{
Install software
}
```

The thing is that the message box is not beeing displayed.
I have been trying
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Update of the current version")

$message=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Update of the current version $($LatestServerVersion)")
$message.WaitForExit

msg.exe $env:username Update of the current version $LatestServerVersion

None of them display the message box.
The message box is correctly displayed if I run the script manually.

Someone has any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: GUI elements will only show if the script runs in the window station of a given interactive user. Please [edit] your question to describe the specific mechanism you use to execute the script. Does _anything_ show when the script runs?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the interest you put into my request.

The script is running if a user opens an interactive session. 
The script doesn't show any window as it is running exclusively in the background and installs all the dependencies silentely.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information, along with additional details about what running in the background, specifically, means. For instance, if you use a scheduled task with a different user identity than the user logging on, the task will run _invisibly_, and you won't be able to show any GUI elements.

Comment: Hello,

I gave up to add this message box.
Thank you for your messages. I am closing this topic.